How to Update SolarWinds Regions for AWS Monitoring?
We recently configured AWS account monitoring using SolarWinds, selecting all available regions for monitoring. However, we later disabled all regions except us-east-1 from AWS Control Tower. Despite this, we’ve noticed that SolarWinds continues to make API calls to all regions, resulting in unnecessary costs. Unfortunately, we’re unable to find the specific settings within SolarWinds to limit monitoring to only the desired regions. Can anyone provide guidance on how to update the regions in SolarWinds for AWS monitoring? We appreciate any insights or solutions to address this issue.
